# resolve this cover url to final destination url in php

Tags: php, url, curl

I need to redirect the advertising URL ($siteURL) to the final destination where this URL normally redirects in a browser. suppose if its redirect on example.com i need example.com as output.

```
$siteURL="http://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click....";

    $ch = curl_init($siteURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_Setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    //print_r($info);
    echo $info['url'];
```

Current output: $siteURL value (no redirect)

Expected output: if its redirect on example.com i need example.com as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the redirect isn't done server-side with a `Location:` header (which `cURL` will follow), but within the browser through a `<meta>` HTML tag.

`$siteURL`'s body contains the following:

```html
...
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www.example.com/?..."> 
...
```

`cURL` doesn't follow HTML/JavaScript redirects, only the browsers do, so you need to actually parse `$siteURL`'s body and manually extract the link.

**test.php** (**EDIT:** handle both HTTP header *and* HTML/JS redirects)

```
<?php

$urls = array (
    "http://some.domain.test/AFClick.asp?...",
    "http://another.domain.example/click?..."
);

foreach ($urls as $siteURL) {
    $ch = curl_init($siteURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    print("\nOriginal URL: ${siteURL}\n");
    if (empty($info['redirect_url'])) {
        preg_match('/<meta http-equiv="refresh".*url=(http.*)">/', $response, $matches);
        print("Redirects to: ${matches[1]}\n");
    } else {
        print("Redirects to: ${info['redirect_url']}\n");
    }

    curl_close($ch);
}

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Original URL: http://some.domain.test/AFClick.asp?...
Redirects to: https://target.example.net/?...

Original URL: http://another.domain.example/click?...
Redirects to: http://target.example.org/?...
```

Comment: i am thinking same but i cant able to make reg exp for getting meta refresh :D

Comment: but bro its not working for $siteURL="http://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p(245446)a(1291517)g(21669022)epi(3iw19bbmtrmv5o4eeu21s4et2ma7wtn7)"
:(

Comment: That's because the second link uses header redirect server-side. I've edited the code to handle both cases.

Comment: thxs bro your guideline and demo code mean alot 
can you guide me what about this link 
$siteURL="http://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p(799)a(1519150)g(21225622)epi(mnaqoymn9uvxpx045kuuhfylpes5v)url(https://www.ebookers.ie/Hotel-Search?rfrr=page.Global-Merch.sl.seasonal.Deals.1.groupByDestination.5#destination=New+York%2C+United+States+of+America&startDate=28%2F11%2F2016&endDate=2%2F12%2F2016&sort=deals&selected=15128435)";

Comment: this case is not working
$urls = array (
    "http://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p(245446)a(1291517)g(21669022)epi(3iw19bbmtrmv5o4eeu21s4et2ma7wtn7)&f=0",
 "http://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p(799)a(1519150)g(21225622)epi(mnaqoymn9uvxpx045kuuhfylpes5v)url(https://www.ebookers.ie/Hotel-Search?rfrr=page.Global-Merch.sl.seasonal.Deals.1.groupByDestination.5#destination=New+York%2C+United+States+of+America&startDate=28%2F11%2F2016&endDate=2%2F12%2F2016&sort=deals&selected=15128435)"
);

Comment: Your last URL goes through several layers of header and HTML redirects. The code I posted works for a single redirection. It can be modified to search recursively through the layers but you'll have to do that yourself, sorry.

Comment: I think we can all agree that my answer solved your initial problem and even applies to more input data that was not part of the initial question, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129682/discussion-between-hassan-saeed-and-alindt).

Answer (score 0):

With php's parse_url you shoul get what you need, have a look at their doxumentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
var_dump(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY));
```

**EDIT:**
Sorry.. you need to use parse_str instead of parse_url, see example below:

```
$siteURL="http://scripts.affiliatefuture.com/AFClick.asp?affiliateID=125272&merchantID=6441&programmeID=17908&mediaID=0&tracking=74299X1524119Xa4d1bde1feb3809c50f9f4d03e2f1096&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.poshbingo.co.uk%2F";

parse_str($siteURL, $output);
var_dump($output['url']);
```

Comment: this is just parsing url into parts like array(3) {
  ["host"]=>
  string(15) "www.example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(5) "/path"
  ["query"]=>
  string(17) "googleguy=googley"
}
i need to final destination url where this $siteURL landed

Comment: its not working for $siteURL="http://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p(245446)a(1291517)g(21669022)epi(3iw19bbmtrmv5o4eeu21s4et2ma7wtn7)%22";
its goes to auto moter url when we normal opened in browser but your code shows error